# Low notes and puberty

Tags: voice, vocal-range, voice-training, vocal-cords, bass-voice

So I've been thinking... I'm almost 18 years old and, after puberty, I can't seem to be able to reach a low D or C. My range ends at about E2-Eb2 depending on the day and I can project those, E2 at least, pretty well. Do I have to practice in order to get a good solid D2-C#2 (maybe even a C2), will they come with age as my voice matures or am I confined to what I have now for the rest of my life with no hopes of extending it just a bit further down?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, Nick. We've got to unpack some things.

1. Your voice doesn't mature at the same rate as the rest of you. Believe it or not, your voice won't really reach full "maturity" until your early-mid 30's. It is *very* common for people's voices (especially trained singers) to change several times before it matures (i.e. "settles").
2. Do you have to practice? Well, I'll answer with more questions: Do you want more control over your voice? Do you want to improve the timbral quality of your tone? Do you want to extend your vocal range? Do you want to take care of your voice as you age? If you answered "yes" to any of those questions, then, yes, you should practice.
3. Vocal range is relatively fluid. Yes, there are trends that we put into categories because we're human and humans like categories. But your voice can and will change over time. The human voice is not fixed over the course of a person's life. There are places where you voice feels comfortable and there are places your voice can go but will make it very tired. You can change where those places are with training, and those places also change on their own as you age. The trick is to be sensitive and aware of those changes and to learn how to bring out the best of your voice, whatever that may be.